# Select "YYYY" component only from DateTime column

Tags: sql, datetime, select

Using SQLCe, I have a column of DateTime type. I would like to filter just by year. Is it possible or should I store year separately, which seems to me redundant?
E.g. get distinct results of 2010,2011,2013. 
Thanks

Comment: I deleted my answer because it wasn't useful to your clarified question, but I'm not entirely sure what you do mean. Do you have results like `2010/01/01 x` / `2010/10/01 x` / `2010/12/01 y` / `2011/01/01 y` that you want to turn into `2010 x` / `2010 y` / `2011 y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think you have the `DATEPART` function (but not the `YEAR` function)

so

```
select DatePart(yyyy, <yourDateTime>)
```

or if that's for ordering, of course

```
order by DatePart(yyyy, <yourDatetime>)
```

**EDIT**

```
select max(InvoiceID)
from yourTable
where DatePart(yyyy, IssuedDate) = 2013
```

Comment: Sorry I am bit new to this..so if my column is called IssuedDate and I want to get the highest InvoiceID in year 2013, what would the query look like?

Comment: @KhDonen If I understand your question correctly, which is that you want the highest InvoiceID for *every* year, then it wouldn't be filtering, that wouldn't be ordering, that would be grouping. Something like `select datepart(yyyy, IssuedDate), max(InvoiceID) from table group by datepart(yyyy, IssuedDate)`? (If you want it for one specific year, my now deleted answer would have worked.)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to use a range filter:

```
select *
from table
where datecolumn >= '2012/01/01' and datecolumn < '2013/01/01'
```

This has the benefit that any index you may have on `datecolumn` can be used.

Since the answer you accepted shows that you only care about one single year, your objection to this answer doesn't really apply.

```
select max(InvoiceID)
from table
where IssuedDate >= '2012/01/01' and IssuedDate < '2013/01/01'
```

will work just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I would like to get records sorted by year only but without specifiying it. As if it was a column storing YEAR only so I could use distinct etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEPART` function to return the year for that column:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, datetimecolumn) FROM YourTable
```

You can then filter with a where clause:

```
WHERE datetimecolumn = 2014
```